# MatLab - Automated plotting of differently sized segments of a text file

Tags: matlab, plot, split, text-files

I have a text file with two columns containing space-delimited numeric data. The data are divided into segments, where each of them contains a **variable** number of rows and the beginning of the next segment is indicated by a single row of **`NaN`** (so the data below would be comprised of four segments):

---

`5.1` [space] `0.0`
`9.2` [space] `1.4`
`3.7` [space] `0.6`
`...` [space] `...`
`...` [space] `...`
`...` [space] `...`
**`NaN`** [space] **`NaN`** 
`9.7` [space] `6.3`
`1.4` [space] `1.0`
`...` [space] `...`
`...` [space] `...`
**`NaN`** [space] **`NaN`** 
`8.7` [space] `0.0`
`5.1` [space] `7.4`
`3.7` [space] `2.6`
`...` [space] `...`
**`NaN`** [space] **`NaN`** 
`1.7` [space] `8.4`
`...` [space] `...`

*and so forth...*

---

Now I'd like to generate a plot displaying a curve for each data segment in the file (by plotting each segments `1st` column against its `2nd` column). 
 
I know how to do this if

- the number of rows in each segment is the same and
- the number of segments is known.

How can that be done efficiently when there's a variable segment size and an unknown number of segments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generated some random data similar to your file. Text file like the one you described can be loaded like this (`load` correctly handles NaNs):

```
Data = load(filename, '-ascii');
```

I know that this code is not perfect, but it works for arbitrary number of segments separated by NaNs.

```
% Here I generate some random points to test the code
NPoints                     = 100;

Data                        = rand(NPoints,2);
% Insert NaNs in both columns
Data( Data(:,1)>0.9, : )    = NaN;

% Now do some magic
idxNaN                          = find( isnan( Data(:,1) ) );
idxNearNaNs                     = [ idxNaN-1 idxNaN+1 ]';
SegmentStartEnd                 = reshape( [1;idxNearNaNs(:);NPoints] , 2, [] )';
SegmentsOK                      = ( SegmentStartEnd(:,2) - SegmentStartEnd(:,1) ) >= 0;
SegmentStartEnd( ~SegmentsOK,:) = [];

% SegmentStartEnd contain start and end rows of good segments
NumberOfSegments = size(SegmentStartEnd,1);
fprintf('NaNs positions: %s\n', sprintf('%g ',idxNaN));
fprintf('%d segments found\n', NumberOfSegments);

% Now plot the data
figure;
hold all;
for k=1:NumberOfSegments
    SegmentStart    = SegmentStartEnd(k,1);
    SegmentEnd      = SegmentStartEnd(k,2);
    fprintf('Segment #%04d: Rows %04d to %04d\n', k, SegmentStart,SegmentEnd);
    plot( Data(SegmentStart:SegmentEnd,1) , Data(SegmentStart:SegmentEnd,2) );
end
```

Let me know if you need some explanations.

Comment: Wow, thank you VERY much for the quick help. I don't understand every detail of the code, but I don't think I need to ;) I'll try it out and see if the code does what I'd like it to do..

Comment: @classifire, no problem. As a side effect this code skips empty segments (two consecutive rows with NaNs; NaNs in first or last rows of data).

Comment: Great, I really appreciate your effort - there's no way I would have been able to figure this code out by myself.